# Iterating over directory and its file contents. Find and replace EXACT match

Tags: python, regex

I wrote a Python script that iterates over all files in a specific directory. It opens files in read-only mode, finds specific strings from an XML file, and replaces them accordingly.

The problem is, if, for example, I want to change "**icon.png**" to "**bear.png**", the script will also work on "professional_**icon.png**" and will replace it with "professional_**bear.png**" - it is not what I want to achieve.

```
import sys
import re
import os
import shutil
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET


drc = '/home/user/Desktop/Convert_here'
backup = '/home/user/Desktop/Rename_icons/tmp_backup'
tree = ET.parse('list.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
records = []

for child in root:
    find = child.find('FINDEXACT').text
    replace = child.find('REPLACEEXACT').text
    records.append((find, replace))
            
    pattern = re.compile(find)
        
    for dirpath, dirname, filename in os.walk(drc):
        for fname in filename:
            path = os.path.join(dirpath, fname) 
            strg = open(path).read() 
            if re.search(pattern, strg):
                print path, strg
                shutil.copy2(path, backup) 
                strg = strg.replace(find, replace) 
                f = open(path, 'w') 
                f.write(strg) 
                f.close()
```

**list.xml**:

```
<SEARCH>
<SEARCHFOR>
    <FINDEXACT>icon.png</FINDEXACT>
    <REPLACEEXACT>bear.png</REPLACEEXACT>
</SEARCHFOR>
<SEARCHFOR>
    <FINDEXACT>professional_icon.png</FINDEXACT>
    <REPLACEEXACT>wolf.png</REPLACEEXACT>
</SEARCHFOR>
</SEARCH>
```

I tried to change `pattern = re.compile(find)` to `pattern = re.match(find, replace)` but it does not seem to work at all. Is there a way to change this script so it only works for exact matches?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you check and compare the length of the search string and the filename?

Comment: This script only works by opening specific files, for example, .txt; .ui; .cpp; .h; .py etc 
I am writing it to use it for rewriting old user interface (Qt .ui). There is tons of icon names to change and tons of .ui forms..

Comment: Do you have to use `re`? Would it not be simpler to just check the file name against the desired name using `==`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you only want to do the substitution when the match is immediately preceded by a non-word character or start of the string. So:

Use as your regular expression:

```
find = r'\b' + child.find('FINDEXACT').text
```

And then you should use a regular expression substitution:

```
strg = pattern.sub(replace, strg)
```

You should also close your input files.